# Динамически определяемые ассоциативные массивы в свойствах объекта

Tags: php

Существует класс Config вот один из его методов:

```
    public function set($item, $value, $config = null) {

        if($config) {

            if(!isset($this->$config))
                $this->$config = array();

            $this->$config[(string)$item] = $value;

        }

        else
            $this->$item = $value;
    }
```

Однако, эта конструкция не работает, вместо того, чтобы инициализировать в свойстве объекта (массиве) новый элемент ($item => $value), получается, что в объекте создается новое свойство с именем первой буквы $config, т.е. так:

```
  $this->set('host', '192.168.190.13', 'database');
  var_dump($this);

  public 'database' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'd' => 
    array (size=1)
      'host' => string '192.168.190.13' (length=11)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить этот момент? Существует ли путь без стандартного ArrayAccess?

Comment: Не верится. Вы уверены, что правильно работаете со свойствами класса?  

К свойствам класса обращаются без доллара:  

    $this->property;

    $test="property";
    $this->$test; // то же что и $this->property;
Если же Вы знаете как работать с классами в PHP, и мои сомнения напрасны, то приведите код "магического" метода класса  

    __set

Comment: __set дефолтный. Ну а как там еще правильно обратиться, если имя свойства задается динамически? ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо заключать в фигурные скобки:

```
public function set($item, $value, $config = null) {

    if($config) {

        if(!isset($this->$config))
            $this->$config = array();

        $this->{$config}[$item] = $value;
    }

    else
        $this->$item = $value;
}
```

Так тоже должно в принципе работать:

```
    if($config) {

        if(isset($this->$config))
            $arrValue = $this->$config;
        else
            $arrValue = array();
        $arrValue[(string)$item] = $value;

        $this->$config = $arrValue;
    }
```

---

Аналог того, что предложили в другом ответе:

```
class Test{
public function set($item, $value, $config = null) {

    if($config) {

        if(!isset($this->$config))
            $this->{$config} = array();

        $this->{$config}[(string)$item] = $value;

    }

    else
        $this->$item = $value;
 }
 public function add(){
   $this->set('host', '192.168.190.13', 'database');
   var_dump($this);
 }
 }
 $obj = new Test();
 $obj->add();
```

Вывод:

> object(Test)#1 (1) { ["database"]=> array(1) { ["host"]=> string(14) "192.168.190.13" } }

Answer (score 2):

```
  class Test{
   public function set($item, $value, $config = null) {

        if($config) {
            if(!isset($this->$config))
                $this->$config = array();
            $this->{$config}[$item] = $value;
        }

        else
            $this->item = $value;
    }
    public function add(){
      $this->set('host', '192.168.190.13', 'database');
      var_dump($this);
    }
    }
    $obj = new Test();
    $obj->add();
object(Test)#1 (1) { ["database"]=> array(1) { ["host"]=> string(14) "192.168.190.13" } }
```

Comment: ну тогда запишется в поле **config** а не в поле **database**

Comment: Изменил, чтобы не возникло путаницы. Правильный ответ- у @IVsevolod